# Could you please recommend some open courses on Real Analysis, mainly about Lebesgue measure and Lebesgue Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am a Chinese student and will be enrolled in the course about Lebesgue integral. I want some open courses to help preview the course. A little bit content about functional analysis is okay.
Thank you!

Comment: Any measure theory book will do. Have a look at Folland's real analysis, Royden's real analysis and Cohn's measure theory.

Comment: Sorry I want the open course about Lebesgue measure and integral. I now correct my question.

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-125-measure-and-integration-fall-2003/lecture-notes/

Comment: Since virtually every college course on integration and measure theory uses the Lebesgue integral nowadays, I imagine virtually every open course does too.

Comment: @Fred Thanks but I wonder whether there are course videos?

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this](https://uccs1.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Sessions/List.aspx#folderID=%22c9bff912-c62b-43a6-92f7-a9d3000c2631%22) useful for real analysis, and [this](https://uccs1.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Sessions/List.aspx#folderID=%2220ef52c3-27e9-409d-b2bb-a9d20186a2e0%22) for functional analysis.

Moreover, you can find more video courses [here](https://uccs1.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Sessions/List.aspx#folderID=%225d51902f-8c62-4ab6-b7a1-a97d00f14697%22) about some other topics in mathematics.

If Chinese is OK to you, [this](https://www.bilibili.com/video/av25179480/?p=1) course from Shanghai Jiao Tong University is acessible.

Answer (score 0):

[This course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLo4jXE-LdDTQq8ZyA8F8reSQHej3F6RFX), available on Youtube, was given at [IMPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instituto_Nacional_de_Matem%C3%A1tica_Pura_e_Aplicada).

> **Content:**
>
> Lecture 01: Introduction: a non-measurable set
> Lecture 02: Classes of subsets (semi-algebras, algebras and sigma-algebras), and set functions
> Lecture 03: Set functions
> Lecture 04: Caratheodory theorem
> Lecture 05: Monotone classes
> Lecture 06: The Lebesgue measure
> Lecture 07: The Lebesgue measure, II
> Lecture 08: Complete measures
> Lecture 09: Approximation theorems
> Lecture 10: Integration: measurable and simple functions
> Lecture 11: Measurable functions
> Lecture 12: Definition of the integral
> Lecture 13: Integral of simple functions
> Lecture 14: Properties of the integral, 01
> Lecture 15: Properties of the integral, 02
> Lecture 16: Theorems on the convergence of integrals.
> Lecture 17: Product measures.
> Lecture 18: Measure on a countable product of spaces
> Lecture 19: Fubini's Theorem
> Lecture 20: Hahn-Jordan Theorem
> Lecture 21: Radon-Nikodym Theorem
> Lecture 22: Almost sure and almost uniform
> Lecture 23: Convergence in Measure
> Lecture 24: Hölder and Minkowski inequalities
> Lecture 25: L_p spaces
> Lecture 26: From convergence in measure to convergence in L_p
> Lecture 27: Bounded linear operators in L_p
> Lecture 28: Vitali's covering lemma
> Lecture 29: Differentiability of functions of bounded variations
> Lecture 30: Absolutely continuous functions
> Lecture 31: Decomposition of distribution
> Lecture 32: Cantor ternary set and function